# How to navigate html forms and save their input using php mysql without proceeding to .php file page?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have 2 html forms. first page is registration page and next is login page. I managed to send the input from registration page to mysql using a php file named connect.php. the 'proceed' button in registration page will navigate to the php file but now i want the 'proceed' button in registration page link to login page and not the connect.php file nd update mysql. i tried putting the connect.php's codes into the registration page's html code but it didnt seem to work. Where should i put the php code in my html code and am i suppose to use bootstrap?

this is my connect.php code:

```
<?php

$name = $_POST['name'];
$age = $_POST['age'];
$gender = $_POST['gender'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

$host = "localhost";
$dbusername = "root";
$dbpassword = "";
$dbname = "ktm_member";

//Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($host, $dbusername, $dbpassword, $dbname);

if (!empty($username))
{
    if (!empty($password))
    {

        if (mysqli_connect_error())
        {
            die ('Connect error('.mysqli_connect_errno().')'.mysqli_connect_error());
        }
        else
        {
            $sql = "INSERT INTO `member list`(`name`, `age`, `gender`, `email`, `username`, `password`) VALUES ('$_POST[name]', '$_POST[age]', '$_POST[gender]', '$_POST[email]', '$_POST[username]', '$_POST[password]')";
            if ($conn->query($sql))
            {
                echo "New record added successfully.";
            }
            else
            {
                echo "Error".$sql."<br>".$conn->error;
            }
            $conn->close();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Password should not be empty";
    }
}
else
{
    echo "Username should not be empty";
    die();
}

?>
```

and this is my registration page html code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html><head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"> 
<title>Register Page</title>

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./W3.CSS Template_files/w3.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./W3.CSS Template_files/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
<style>
body,h1 {font-family: "Raleway", sans-serif}
body, html {height: 100%}
.bgimg {
    background-image: url('forestbridge.jpg');
    min-height: 100%;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
}
</style>
</head>
<body><div class="bgimg w3-display-container w3-animate-opacity w3-text-white"><div class="w3-display-middle">
<center><h2>Register</h2></center>
      <form name="form1" method="post" action="welcomeloginpage.php" autocomplete = "off">
        <p class="w3-large w3-center">
          <label for="name">Name: </label>
          <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Your full name" autofocus required>
        </p>
        <p class="w3-large w3-center">
          <label for="age">Age: </label>
          <input type="number" name="age" id="age">
        </p>
        <p class="w3-large w3-center">
          <label for="gender">Gender: </label>
          <input type="radio" name="gender" value="M"> Male
          <input type="radio" name="gender" value="F"> Female<br> <id="gender">
        </p>
        <p class="w3-large w3-center">
          <label for="email">Email: </label>
          <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="xxx@xx.xx">
        </p> 
        <p class="w3-large w3-center">
          <label for="username">Username: </label>
          <input type="text" name="username" id="username">
        </p>
        <p class="w3-large w3-center">
          <label for="password">Password: </label>
          <input type="password" name="password" id="password" maxlength="10" placeholder="password" data-toggle="password">
        </p>
        <p style="text-align: center;">
          <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit">
        </p>
      </form>
```

Comment: You need to use ajax and some web development manuals.

Comment: Bootstrap is a choice and not a prerequisite

Comment: You can also post the form to a PHP page that handles the data (stores it in database etc) and then just redirect the user to where you want. Just end the script with `header('location: /to/some/page.php'); exit;`. Just remember not to have any output at all before the `header()`-call.

Comment: @Alberto Can you suggest me links? Because i dont know how to word out what i want to search in google to search for any guidance. Any link would be very helpful to me.

Comment: **Warning:** You are wide open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should really use parameterized [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of manually building your queries like that. Specially since you're not escaping the user inputs at all!

Comment: **Warning:** _Never store passwords in clear text!_ You should _only_ store password hashes! Use PHP's [`password_hash()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and [`password_verify()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php).

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Okay will do. Thank you.

Comment: Oh sorry @MagnusEriksson My answer looks like I have nicked all your good suggestions :(

Comment: @RiggsFolly - I used a clipboard tool while you spent time writing a proper answer, I think you win :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want your `connect.php` script to send the user to another page if the registration is successful then you use a `header()` command like this

```
<?php

$name = $_POST['name'];
$age = $_POST['age'];
$gender = $_POST['gender'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

$host = "localhost";
$dbusername = "root";
$dbpassword = "";
$dbname = "ktm_member";

//Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($host, $dbusername, $dbpassword, $dbname);

if (!empty($username)) {
    if (!empty($password)) {

        if (mysqli_connect_error()) {
            die ('Connect error('.mysqli_connect_errno().')'
                    .mysqli_connect_error());
        } else {

            // this query style is very dangerous see note below
            $sql = "INSERT INTO `member list`
                        (`name`, `age`, `gender`, 
                         `email`, `username`, `password`) 
                    VALUES ('$_POST[name]', '$_POST[age]', '$_POST[gender]', 
                            '$_POST[email]', '$_POST[username]', '$_POST[password]')";
            if ($conn->query($sql)) {
                // remove echo as you will never see it now
                //echo "New record added successfully.";
                header('Location: otherPage.php');
                exit;   // important as header does not stop code execution in this script
            } else {
                echo "Error".$sql."<br>".$conn->error;
            }
            $conn->close();
        }
    } else {
        echo "Password should not be empty";
    }
} else {
    echo "Username should not be empty";
    die();
}
?>
```

> You do have at least 2 serious flaws in this code though that I must mention.
>
> Your script is wide open to [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)
>   Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string)
>   Use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) in either the `MYSQLI_` or `PDO` API's
>
> Never store plain Text password in your database. The most likely place where these things get compromised is from within the company running this database. An unhashed password is a total givaway for a DB Admin who just got refused a pay rise!
>
> PHP provides [`password_hash()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php)
>   and [`password_verify()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) please use them.
>   And here are some [good ideas about passwords](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Password_Storage_Cheat_Sheet)
>   If you are using a PHP version prior to 5.5 [there is a compatibility pack available here](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat)